# MYSQL Query to find matches LIKE

Tags: mysql

I have a tabel with 2 rows. ID and FILTER.

In the FILTER row i have added The.White.Tiger.

Running this query :

```
SELECT id
FROM filter
WHERE filter LIKE CONCAT( '%', 'The.White.Tiger', '%' )
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Returns 1 result, the ID.

But i need it to find a result nomater whats els is in the title.

```
 SELECT id
 FROM filter
 WHERE filter LIKE CONCAT( '%', 'The.White.Tiger.At.My.House', '%' )
 LIMIT 0 , 30
```

This returns no result, but i need to make the query so that it dos still find it.
Any ideer on how to do that?

As long as the string thats are in FILTER row is in the start of the title string it should ignore the rest
Tabel struckture

```
1   id  int(11)         AUTO_INCREMENT          
2   filter  varchar(255)    latin1_swedish_ci
```

Comment: What exactly do you need??

Comment: I need it to return the id of the row that contains the filter.

i Have : The.White.Tiger. in the database.

So i need i query that returns the id to me, no mater whats type AFER. 

So that : The.White.Tiger.bla.bla.bla.bla

Will still return the id of the colum : The.White.Tiger.

As the query is now, it only returns if use : The.White.Tiger. as soon as i type some after, it returns nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Then Remove the filter from your where clause ::

```
SELECT *
 FROM filter

 LIMIT 0 , 30
```

If you need record having filter starting with 'The.White.Tiger' 
Try :

```
SELECT id
FROM filter
WHERE filter LIKE 'The.White.Tiger%'
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Comment: This will return all thats in the database?

Thats not what i want... I want it to find the id of the row that have The.White.Tiger. in filter coloum.

So it returns the id of The.White.Tiger, no matter whats els in the titel, if the title starts with a string thats in the database under Filter, it should return the ID

Comment: What is title now? Please provide an example, which can help me easily to figure the question

Comment: This is present in filter row in the database : The.White.Tiger.
It need it to return a result on The.White.Tiger.At.My.House

Comment: If there is no record in the db which has a filter named The.White.Tiger.At.My.House, how will you expect the db to return a row...

Comment: I need it to find the row The.White.Tiger because the title has that in the beginning The.White.Tiger.At.My.House start with The.White.Tiger. therefor i need it to return that to me

Comment: LIKE CONCAT( '%', 'The.White.Tiger.At.My.House', '%' )
i am using a like?

Comment: This will return you all the rows which will have filters containing the full string ::

1) asasasThe.White.Tiger.At.My.Housesasas
2) abcThe.White.Tiger.At.My.Housexyz
any thing on the edges, but the filters should contain the complete string

Comment: Is there now why to search the filter row for if the titel startstring is in the filter database?

Comment: What i need is for it tó search the filter database for a filter (in this case the.White.Tiger.) and see if the title start with something thats in the database.

Comment: If I understood what you need, then kindly check my 2nd query, may be it will return you your desired rows

Comment: Return 0 rows the second query